# Erro de sintaxe concatenação

Tags: javascript

A minha função retorna o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Como posso corrigir?

```
function setarRegistro() {
    campos = "teste="+encodeURI(document.getElementById('teste').value).
    "&nome="+encodeURI(document.getElementById('nome').value).
    "&sobrenome="+encodeURI(document.getElementById('sobrenome').value).
    "&usuario="+encodeURI(document.getElementById('usuario').value).
    "&email="+encodeURI(document.getElementById('email').value).
    "&senha="+encodeURI(document.getElementById('senha').value);
}
```

Comment: Curiosidade: por quê em um momento você usa `+` para concatenar e em outros você usa o `.`?

Comment: Você deve utilizar o `+` para concatenar.

Comment: Tá confundindo PHP com JavaScript?

Comment: Como eu disse, estava testando, justamente o erro foi a concanetação, tinha visto em algum lugar o uso de . e achei que funcionaria, agradeço as respostas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize "+" para concatenar no JavaScript, o "." é utilizado para acessar a propriedade ou função de um objeto.

Answer (score 0):

No javascript o operador de concatenação é o +. Basta substituir os . por + conforme abaixo.

```
function setarRegistro() {
   campos = "teste="+encodeURI(document.getElementById('teste').value)+
   "&nome="+encodeURI(document.getElementById('nome').value)+
   "&sobrenome="+encodeURI(document.getElementById('sobrenome').value)+
   "&usuario="+encodeURI(document.getElementById('usuario').value)+
   "&email="+encodeURI(document.getElementById('email').value)+
   "&senha="+encodeURI(document.getElementById('senha').value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Resposta**

Em php pode concatenar com o "." em javascript deve usar "+", no seu código estão misturados.

```
function setarRegistro() {
    campos = "teste=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById('teste').value) +
    "&nome=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById('nome').value) +
    "&sobrenome=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById('sobrenome').value) +
    "&usuario=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById('usuario').value) +
    "&email=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById('email').value) +
    "&senha=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById('senha').value);
}
```